Why are my users disconnecting from their socket but reconnecting with the same socket id?
I'm confused debugging my Node.js, React, socket.io web game. My users have been disconnecting randomly from their game rooms with reason transport close (I'm still working out why...)
My current disconnect handling (for all disconnect events) sends a message to the client to show the user a modal that says they've been removed from the room and a button to return to home screen. But when they return to home screen, they reconnect to the server with the same socket id.
User Connected with socket id: klzkr-QJmatX_KvbAAA6
id klzkr-QJmatX_KvbAAA6 disconnected, reason: transport close
User Connected: klzkr-QJmatX_KvbAAA6

But when my users close the window or tab manually, then go to my web page again, they connect with a different socket.id.
id klzkr-QJmatX_KvbAAA6 disconnected, reason: transport close
User Connected with socket id: Eq7kw_s_0KgBbk2iAAA-

This is my code:
const io = new Server(server, { // for work with socket.io
  cors: corsOptions,
  connectionStateRecovery: {
    maxDisconnectionDuration: 2 * 60 * 1000, // 2 mins backup
    skipMiddlewares: true,
  }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log(`User ${socket.id} disconnected because: ${reason}`);
    io.to(socket.data.roomCode).emit("return_to_home");
    game.removePlayer(socket.id);

My questions are:

Like in the title, how are the users that randomly disconnected able to keep their original socket id? That means that there's SOME way that their socket connection was maintained no? In that case why were they disconnected at all?
How can I make sure my users don't get kicked from rooms from unintentional transport close's, when manual disconnects also have transport close reason?
I thought socket.io has an under the hood pingpong/heartbeat system where they make sure users don't disconnect randomly? How come my users are disconnecting?


On some platforms, sockets are represented by file descriptors, and file descriptors can be reused after they are closed. Maybe your socket ids are reflecting that? You probably need to create your own unique IDs to identify players, perhaps tied to login credentials rather than to the socket itself.

My users don't need to login, just enter their username for each session. Should I just generate a uuid for each player then when they first join? But then how do I know if I need to generate a new one when they reconnect with the same socket ID?

How can you possibly be sending a message to a client that has already disconnected?

@user207421 oop , I copied my code wrong, it emits an event to the whole room and the client sees it

Not if he’s already disconnected.

@chung are these duplicate socket IDs actually causing a real problem for you, other than in your logs? A socket is unique only while the connection is active. Once the socket is closed, all bets are off on it.

Hmm I guess what I'm concerned about is just what's happening WHEN the ids are being reused. Because it's only happening when a user unintentionally disconnects... @RemyLebeau

@RemyLebeau Also I was wondering if I need to cleanup certain sockets when they disconnect, when a user reconnects with the same socket.id, does their socket.data get reset?
